# How do I update a generic class-view?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a django app that stores information on different profiles of people. I want to be able to provide a downloadable spreadsheet and update a class-view(ListView) on the website using the same url. I don't fully understand class views yet and I'm struggling to figure out how to combine the two view functions below.

I tried this:
views.py

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    #template_name = 'search.html'
    def get(self, request):
        return export_profiles(request)

def export_profiles(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="profile_list.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Name','Title','Location','Phone','Email','Company Name','Company Size','Link'])
    data = Profile.objects.filter()
    for row in data:
        rowobj = [row.name,row.title,row.location,row.phone,row.email,row.GetCompany().companyName,row.GetCompany().companySize,row.url]
        writer.writerow(rowobj)
    #Clean up database
    return response
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('profiles/', ProfileList.as_view()),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('session_security/', include('session_security.urls')),
]
```

This worked for downloading the file, but still didn't update the profile list with the django as_view() function. It just downloaded the csv file without erroring.

This is what I currently have:

views.py

```
#Post a view of profiles on the website when a search is initiated
class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'search.html'  

@login_required
def export_profiles(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="profile_list.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Name','Title','Location','Phone','Email','Company Name','Company Size','Link'])
    data = Profile.objects.filter()
    for row in data:
        rowobj = [row.name,row.title,row.location,row.phone,row.email,row.GetCompany().companyName,row.GetCompany().companySize,row.url]
        writer.writerow(rowobj)

    return response
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('search/', views.search, name='search'),
    path('profiles/', views.export_profiles, name='profiles'),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    url('session_security/', include('session_security.urls')),
]
```

search.html

```
<div class="column">
            <h3>Profiles</h3>
            <font color="red">
                <p>The following list does not save after the next search you make! Please save the csv file placed in your browser downloads folder.</p>
            </font>
            {% for profile in object_list %}
            <ul>
                <li>Name: {{ profile.name }}</li>
                <li>Title: {{ profile.title }}</li>
                <li>Location: {{ profile.location }}</li>
                <li>Phone: {{ profile.phone }}</li>
                <li>Email: {{ profile.email }}</li>
                <li>Company Name: {{ profile.GetCompany.companyName }}</li>
                <li>Company Size: {{ profile.GetCompany.companySize }}</li>
                <li>Link: <a href={{ profile.url }}>{{ profile.url }}</a></li>
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
            <br />
        </div>
```

Am I right to be trying to combine a django class-view and another view function under one url? A full solution would be nice but a lot to ask for. I'm just asking for some pointers and links to further educate myself on this problem.

Comment: You cannot have 1 view returning a http and a file response. You need to have 2 views

Comment: can I redirect to another url in one view function/class to call the other?